# Putting app.get() routes ina separate file

Tags: node.js, express

I have this ordinary expressjs app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and i want to remove

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

and put them in a separate file.I am trying this

```
module.exports = function(/* any dependency? */){
 app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
}
```

and in the `app.js` file i have `require('./routed.js');`

but this do not work.How should i fix this?.

Answer (score 1):

I took krasu's answer and modified a bit

`routed.js`

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');

module.exports = function(app){
 app.get('/', routes.index);
 app.get('/users', user.list);
}
```

in `app.js`

```
require('./routed.js')(app);
```

and this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./routed.js')(app);
```

And in `./routed.js`

```
module.exports = function(app){
 app.get('/', routes.index);
 app.get('/users', user.list);
}
```

Comment: I fixed it a bit but it works but i do not know the performance cost that comes with it.

Comment: You will need `var routes = require('./routes');var user = require('./routes/user');` in the `routed.js` file for this to work.